# The Command "grunt" exited with code 3 error when building project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I am unfamiliar with Grunt and I tried to follow steps to install it. I am getting this error and I have tried for a week to get it to work. Can anyone please help me. I am an undergrad student and don't have that much know how with it. I followed the installation instructions on the website. and know its a task error. but after that I cant find any working solutions. 
[image]

Comment: Exit code 3 is a [task error](http://gruntjs.com/api/exit-codes). Maybe you could include the contents of the `gruntfile.js` in your question? And the output that the `grunt` command writes to the console would also be helpful.

Comment: please include your gruntfile.js your package json, for we do a full help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error is inside the js file.

Answer (score 0):

npm rebuild node-sass

This one helped me.